# Upgrading from ArcGIS 10.3 (Desktop & Server), what version to choose?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-10.5, upgrade

We are currently on 10.3 (Desktop & Server) and have been for 5+ years. Looking to upgrade to new version, cannot go to 10.6.1 due to third party software compatibility.

I have been told (by Esri) that upgrading Desktop up multiple versions is fine, but jumping ArcGIS Server (from 10.3 - 10.5.1) could cause issues. It was recommended to step up the Server upgrade (10.3 to 10.4 to 10.5).

We have the specs for all versions up 10.6 (SQL, RAM, etc.) I recently tried to upgrade on my desktop from 10.3 to 10.6 and it completely crushed my CPU (64 bit, i7 2.70 GHz 16GB RAM . Needed to get my computer reformatted, probably wasn't related to Esri and more than likely hardware/video card issues but it makes me hesitant to push 20 end users up to 10.6 and jump my ArcGIS Server to 10.6 and risk headaches and issues.

I am personally thinking moving up to the stable 10.5.1 and calling it good, including making the jump from 10.3 to 10.5.1 on server. I am aware of the changes that occur at 10.5x+ with ArcGIS Enterprise.

Any similar experiences, insight, or advice?

Comment: or 10.7? https://mobile.twitter.com/eilenens/status/1093921252669046786

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question/Best answer" model operates.  This question is too like a discussion request to survive in our Q&A format. In the end, only you can decide which version of software to run. Some folks install the hottest new stuff as soon as it reaches Beta. Others need 3-6 months to decide to move, an will only advance one release at a time.  You're far enough back that you're at the cusp of leaving the support envelope, so 10.5.1 or 10.6.1 should be in your sights.

Comment: Do you run standalone or concurrent licenses? In general, the big stuff (SDE, Server) is a bit behind the desktops but the License Manager can be somewhat ahead. Ask ESRI.

Answer (score 1):

> We have the specs for all versions up 10.6 (SQL, RAM, etc.) I recently tried to upgrade on my desktop from 10.3 to 10.6 and it completely crushed my CPU (64 bit, i7 2.70 GHz 16GB RAM . Needed to get my computer reformatted, probably wasn't related to Esri and more than likely hardware/video card issues

The difference in needed hardware between 10.3 and 10.6 are neglible. Your "crush" is definitely something else. I ran 10.6 fine on a 7 year old second generation Core I5 quadcore desktop with 16 GB RAM up to last year (upgraded to Windows 10 even).

The main jump in hardware specs is if you intend to start explore ArcGIS Pro. I wouldn't run Pro on any machine, including laptops, with less than 32 GB RAM and without a proper fast NVME SSD. I have actually seen Pro consume up to a whopping 71(!) GB of virtual RAM at one point (remember, it is finally 64bit)...